# Trying to query information from a database for a simple ranking algorithm

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am making a simple image browser which is connected to an SQLite database. Within the browser, similar images are grouped into an **event** and each **image** is labelled with a few **tags**.

To reflect this information, the table (all in one table) structure looks a little like this:

```
row_id      tag          image_id          event_id

1           computer      201                 1
2           desk          201                 1
3           chair         201                 1

4           computer      202                 1
5           coffee        202                 1
6           desk          202                 1

7           dog           203                 2
8           phone         203                 2

etc.        etc.         etc.                etc.       // many 1000's
```

Basically the idea is the user can search for any number of tags (e.g. desk, chair & laptop) and receive back a ranked list of event id's. Each event is supposed to be ranked by the amount of images in the event containing all tags, then all tags minus 1, then all tags minus 2, etc.

The goal is come up with a query that returns information like the example below, which I can then sort later. (Obviously the length of the rows will vary depending on how many tags are searched for.)

```
event_id | event_size | no. imgs with 3 tags |  no. imgs with 2 tags |  no. imgs with 1 tag 

   2           74                 6                      24                 55 

   5           20                 2                      4                  14

   3           36                 4                      11                 22
```

Is this possible? The size of the event is just the number of unique image ids it contains. For the rest, I was thinking using some combination of...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN tag = 'computer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

...could achieve it? I'm new to this, so not sure how difficult a question this is.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that the event_size is just the number of unique image_id's it contains.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do it with an arbitrary number of columns determined at runtime, but I think I see a way to get all the counts as the value of a single column that you can then extract and do stuff with. Don't have time to actually write an example right now though... hopefully later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of matching tags per image with something like this:

```
select event_id, image_id, count(*) as num_matches
from t
where tag in ( . . . )
group by event_id, image_id;
```

This filters out any images with no matching tags.  So, instead:

```
select event_id, image_id,
       sum(case when tag in ( . . . ) then 1 else 0 end) as num_matches
from t
group by event_id, image_id;
```

You can then pivot this:

```
select event_id, count(*) as num_images,
       sum(case when num_matches = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as num_3_tags,
       sum(case when num_matches = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as num_2_tags,
       sum(case when num_matches = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_1_tags
from (select event_id, image_id, 
             sum(case when tag in ( . . . ) then 1 else 0 end) as num_matches
      from t
      group by event_id, image_id
     ) t
group by event_id;
```

Comment: Hi, I think I got it working in a fidddle, see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f8WNimjmZAj1XXeCj4PHB8/0

Comment: Have I done something incorrectly? num_2_tags and num_1_tags are not being populated correctly

Comment: @AzzyDude . . . The code looks correct.  I can't figure out why it would not be working.

Comment: I should clarify that num_3_tags should be the number of images in the event containing exactly 3 of the searched tags, then num_2_tags should be the number of images containing exactly 2 of the searched tags, so there should be no overlapping image_id's between num_3_tags and num_2_tags...does that make sense?

Comment: @AzzyDude . . . Total sense.  And the subquery works in the example.  I don't know why the outer aggregation doesn't work.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the way SQLite works?

Comment: @AzzyDude . . . No.  It works now -- all the comparisons were using "3" for `_num_matches`.  This has been fixed in the answer.  Also, try this `order by`: ` ORDER BY num_3_tags DESC, num_2_tags DESC`.